# How to get value from unique id basis varchar datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query; can you help me with it? I have comboAmount and TotalPrice, I want TotalPrice + Combo Amount add into newComboAmount, but it's showing me a wrong result because my ComboUniqueId is different from other please check below picture and query

```
SELECT
    CAST(CASE 
            WHEN a.TotalPrice != 0 
               THEN 1  
               ELSE 0  
         END AS bit) AS CheckOtherPrice, 
    a.OrderDetailId, a.ItemId,
    b.ItemCode, b.ItemName,
    e.GroupName,
    a.Quantity, a.Price, a.TotalPrice,
    a.OrderId, ISNULL(a.ComboId, 0) ComboId, 
    (a.ComboAmount + SUM(a.TotalPrice) OVER (ORDER BY a.OrderDetailId)) AS new_comboamount,  
    a.ComboGroupId, a.ComboAmount, a.ComboUniqueId,
    c.ComboName, d.GroupName ComboGroupName,
    a.OfferMasterId 
FROM
    OrderDetail a
INNER JOIN
    ItemMaster b ON a.ItemId = b.ItemId AND a.OrderId IN (985)
INNER JOIN
    ItemGroup e ON b.ItemGroupId = e.ItemGroupId
LEFT JOIN
    ComboMaster c ON a.ComboId = c.ComboId
LEFT JOIN 
    ComboGroup d ON a.ComboGroupId = d.GroupId
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need a `partition by`:

```
( a.ComboAmount + sum(a.TotalPrice) over (partition by combouniqueid order by a.OrderDetailId) ) as new_comboamount
```